# Bootstrap 4.5.0 CSS 4.0 Compilation Errors Using VS2019

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

When I try to apply themes to my ASP.NET project, VS gets upset with me. I've tried several themes from bootswatch, all with the same errors. An example is... Validation (CSS 4.0): "-ms-flex-positive" is not a known CSS property.

It's throwing dozens of these errors for bootstrap.css. When I use an old version of the same theme from 3.4.1 it only throws a couple of errors... Validation (CSS 4.0): "appearance" is not a known CSS property.

I understand that it's trying to reference values that are supposed to exist somewhere, but I don't know where or what setup I'm doing incorrectly. I've made sure that 4.5.0 is installed in the NuGet Package Manager. What am I missing?

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to compile?  What version of the framework?  .net core? .net legacy?  mvc?

Comment: MVC. I started by creating a new ASP>NET Web Application (.NET Framework) MVC

Comment: Well, i'm unable to recreate the problem.  Typically, validation messages are not errors.. are you sure they're not warnings?

Comment: I suppose warnings is probably more accurate. Please forgive my poor terminology, I am 12 days young in programming. The symbol is what I would think of as a warning symbol. It does compile, but does not display properly, which is why I used the term error. Here is an example of the actual code from the template that is throwing the warning: 
'.flex-lg-shrink-0 {
    -ms-flex-negative: 0 !important;
        flex-shrink: 0 !important;
    }'

Comment: The warning thrown there is 'Validation (CSS 4.0): "-ms-flex-positive" is not a known CSS property' ... from the relatively little I understand, it feels to me like I have an incomplete listing of CSS properties somewhere. In an interesting turn of events, I tried it in IE and Edge and it worked fine. I then went back and tried it in Chrome again and it worked fine. I've been trying to resolve this using only chrome for about a week and this is the first time it worked in Chrome. I wish I understood why.

Comment: one more update...opening it in IE didn't fix anything. Chrome had just cached the 3.4.1 version that displays properly. When I cleared the cache, it still doesn't display properly in chrome or IE when using the 4.5.0 version.